# DLL indexing in Windows Library files

Tags: windows, dll

Recently I have been learning about Windows Library files. I have noticed that from the Windows documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/schema-library-name, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/schema-library-iconreference), there seems to be references to a dll or ModuleFileName for the name and icon reference, with some indexing within the file. However, I am having trouble understanding what is even in these files. From what I understand from Wikipedia and some Googling, they provide functions that can be linked. However, I am not sure how I can see these functions and what they are returning. I have tried to read the file using tools like dumpbin but for example when I view the export table of shell32.dll, I do not see big index numbers suggested in the documentation (-34575) although I have read (https://web.archive.org/web/20101018122506/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/05/05/10007461.aspx) about how the indexing works. Is my understanding completely wrong? What materials should I be reading to understand more about this topic?

I would appreciate any help in pointing me in the right direction.